Windows Command Prompt - Use Folder Structure of One Folder to Execute in Different Folder?
Hard to come up with a title for this, it's difficult to briefly summarize - which also makes it difficult to Google.
Basically, I have a media server. I have a folder for non-HEVC movies and a folder for HEVC movies, since the machine hosting the server cannot re-encode HEVC and doing this allows me to block remote access to those movies. I have x264 versions of everything in the HEVC folder, for remote use. Basically, I have a rip of the 4K disc and a rip of the Blu-ray from double packs. However, this seems like a waste since the only use of the x264 1080p version will be for situations where it's being accessed remotely, or from a low-compatibility device, and thus the full-bitrate 1080p version is kind of unnecessary. So I want to compress them. But I can't think of an easy way to loop through it all.
In my main folder, I have a structure like, for example, "Movies\A\Alien (1979)\Alien (1979) - 1080p.mkv" and then the HEVC folder is "Movies 4K\A\Alien (1979)\Alien (1979) - 4K.mkv". However, I want to act on the main folder but only with the directory list from the 4K folder.
Is there a way to do this? Basically, if "A\Alien (1979)" exists within "Movies 4K," take every .mkv file in "Movies\A\Alien (1979)", and send it to ffmpeg. The last bit is super simple, I just made x264 copies of all my VC1-encoded files with:
for /r %F in (*.mkv) do (ffmpeg -i "%F" -c:v libx264 "TempFolder\%~pnxF")
But there I was acting on the files I was filtering by, which obviously makes it a lot easier.
